# Add functionality to class and all of it's subclasses

Tags: c++, qt, oop, inheritance, methods

I have  3 classes that inherit from 3 different classes which all inherit from `QWidget` base class.
For example:

1. `MyMainWindow : public QMainWindow : public QWidget`
2. `MyPushButton : public QPushButton : public QWidget`
3. `MyTextEdit : public QTextEdit : public QWidget`

And I will have more classes like this eventually.
What I'd like to do now, is add a common method to all my classes; this means it should be added to the `QWidget` base class, but I can't edit it (I'd rather not change the Qt source code for one method).

Is this kind of behaviour possible?
I've already tried using interfaces like so:

```
class MyTextEdit : public QTextEdit, IMyMethodContainer { ... };
```

But the problem is, I need to access `QObject::connect(sender, signal, this, slot);` in `IMyMethodContainer`, and by `this` I'm trying to access the `MyTextEdit`, not the `IMyMethodContainer`, which is not a subclass of `QWidget`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRTP might help.

```
template<typename Derived, typename Base>
struct InjectMethod: Base {
  static_assert( std::is_base_of< InjectMethod<Derived,Base>, Derived >::value, "CRTP violation" );
  Derived* self() { return static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
  Derived const* self() const { return static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
  void my_method() {
    // use self() inside this method to access your Derived state
  }
};
```

Then:

```
class MyTextEdit: InjectMethod< MyTextEdit, QTextEdit > {
};
class MyPushButton: InjectMethod< MyPushButton, QPushButton > {
};
```

inside `InjectMethod< MyTextEdit, QTextEdit >` you have access to a `self()` pointer that has access to all stuff inside `MyTextEdit`, and inside `InjectMethod< MyPushButton, QPushButton >` the same.

You may not need the `Derived` portion -- possibly having a single template parameter (your base) would be enough, if you only use `QWidget` functionality.

Comment: Thank you, lifesavior :) And yeah I won't be using the `Derived` portion, but keep it there, others might need it ^^

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can "extend" QWidget and add your custom methods there.

```
Class MyQWidgetExtension extends QWidget { ... }
```

Your other classes (QMainWindow, QpushButton, QtextEdit) just extend ("inherit") from that. Is there similar for C++?

```
Class MyQWidgetExtension : public QWidget { ... }
```

Comment: The problem is the `QTextObject` that he also doesn't control between the `QWidget` and @Markus's classes.